# How to reset network link in Solaris 11.4

Tags: networking, solaris

I've got a machine running Solaris 11.4 and a few LDOMs, and for a yet-unknown reason, one of the network interfaces decided to step down from 10G to 1G and later to 100M. Is there any command available that can force a reset or re-handshake on that interface, anything that would be similar to replugging the physical network cable? I would like to avoid having to send out a tech to a datacenter just for that. The problematic interface isn't mapped into any LDOM, so resetting the link doesn't cause any issues. I am also reasonably sure that this is not due to a faulty cable or NIC since the same problem exists on several machines in the same rack - this makes me assume it's somehow related to the switch, to which I have no admin access to.

On previous Solaris versions, `ifconfig unplumb/plumb` used to do that, but apparently not anymore.

The newly introduced `ipadm disable-if/enable-if` doesn't seem to reset the physical link either.

`dladm` can show me the interface state but not change it.

Forcing it down with `ndd -set /dev/ixgbe0 interface_state 0` gives me an illegal operation error. Not sure whether that used to work on older versions, I haven't used ndd for many years now.

And the whole `netcfg` command suite only seems to affect VSwitches and related virtual interfaces, but can't touch the physical link either.

Tried it via the ILOM as well, but that only tells me that the Ethernet device can not be stopped.

I can't do an `svcadm restart network/physical` because that would restart all interfaces and most likely kill the running LDOMs (and I'm not sure whether that really does a restart on the physical link either).

Answer (score 2):

This may be too late, but I'll still answer, not only for others but my future self, as I find I need to this frequently. I'm not sure why `ipadm disable-if / enable-if` didn't work for you, as I tested this on Oracle Solaris 11.4:

1. First, determine the IP interface and its state with `ipadm`. In my case it is `net0`
2. Then disable, `sudo ipadm disable-if -t net0`
3. You can double check the state before running the next command, as in step 1.
4. Re-enable, `sudo ipadm enable-if -t net0`

Most information can be found from the Managing Network Configuration documentation, if you need to confirm settings.

Hope this helps.